# jQuery function sync call

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, durandal, jquery-deferred

How could I call a function, then when it's done, call another function passing the first function's return value as parameter? I read a lot about `Deferred` but can't figure out how it works.

https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/ and so on mainly on SO..

Here's some sample:

```
function a() {
   new amodel.AModel().save(vm.elem).done(function(_elem) {
      vm.elem(_elem);      
   }).fail(function(error) {
      ...
});

function b(param) {
  ... 
} //should call this with the a() return value
```

I tried to make it work as the follow:

```
$.when(a()).then(b());
```

This way I can't pass a parameter on, and I'm not even sure if it does what I would like to.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I wrote it wrong. I don't have to pass the return value as parameter, since when function `a` runs and gets done, it sets the value (`vm.elem(_elem)`) which will be used for an ajax call's parameter in function `b`.

Comment: Your example doesn't do anything asynchronously. Have you oversimplified it or does the code in your actual problem do async stuff?

Comment: it's not an async call, but function `b` should be called right after when function `a` is done (both are ajax calls)

Comment: "it's not an async call" and "both are ajax calls" — You just contradicted yourself. Which is true?

Comment: when I say its no async, I mean sync because function `b` doesnt get called while function `a` is running

Comment: It should be `function a() { return an ajax call promise for 10 }` and `a().then(b)`

Comment: thanks for downvoting it helps me a lot to understand how this jquery feature works :) @Bergi is it a must, will it not work as I wrote it?

Comment: okay, got it. And how could I pass the return value of `a` to `b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `a` returned a promise, then it will automagically pass the result on to `b` when chaining together using `then`

Therefore what you want is `a().then(b)`.

Note that `b` is not passed with parentheses, that would pass the result of calling `b` to the chain. What you actually are doing is passing a *reference* to `b` into the chain and say "Call `b` when you have resolved the result of `a`".

Here is a live example which demonstrates: http://jsfiddle.net/9wvb1d2a/

Comment: `a` returns a promise. So its `a().then(b)` instead of `$.when(a()).then(b)`?

Comment: I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. Forgot to mention, I'm using knockout (durandal)

Comment: You've forgotten to `return` the deferred.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me a lot of time and helped me to get a better understanding of this topic :)